# T-SQL Update with Max and Min value from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, update

I don't have much experience with SQL queries and I'm trying to learn and understand from my mistakes.
I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTest
(Id INT,
Number INT)

CREATE TABLE #TempTest2
(Id INT,
MaxNo INT,
MinNo INT)

INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,4)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,6)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,9)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,7)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,3)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #TempTest VALUES (1,5)

INSERT INTO #TempTest2 VALUES (1,0,10)
```

And I'm trying to update the columm `MaxNo` with the max number smaller than 8 from the first table and `MinNo` with the minimum bigger than 1:

```
UPDATE t2
SET MaxNo = IIF(t1.Number>t2.MaxNo AND t1.Number<8,t1.Number, t2.MaxNo),
MinNo = IIF(t1.Number<t2.MinNo AND t1.Number>1,t1.Number, t2.MinNo)
FROM #TempTest2 t2
JOIN #TempTest t1 ON t2.Id=t1.Id
```

But it updated both columns with value 4. I've also tried using

```
BEGIN Transaction
...
COMMIT
```

around the update, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the best approach to update the second table correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `MinNo with the minimum bigger than 1` = will ignor(mark as null) all the records smaller or equal to 1.

```
 CASE WHEN Number <=1 THEN NULL ELSE Number END
```

For `max number smaller than 8` = will ignor(mark as null) all the records greater or equal to 8.

```
 CASE WHEN Number >= 8 THEN NULL ELSE Number END
```

The query will look something like this:

```
UPDATE t2
    SET MaxNo =  t1.MaxNo,
        MinNo = t1.MinNo
FROM 
    #TempTest2 as t2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, 
                MinNo = MIN(CASE WHEN Number <=1 THEN NULL ELSE Number END),
                MaxNo = MAX(CASE WHEN Number >= 8 THEN NULL ELSE Number END)
        FROM 
            #TempTest
        GROUP BY 
            id
    )as t1
    ON t2.Id = t1.Id;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTest2;
```

output:

| Id | MaxNo | MinNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 3 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5df1263bc4069fd3055ce4091ca12f2c)

Answer (score 2):

One way is you can use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to temporarily stage the result set of your min and max values, then `CROSS JOIN` it to your `#TempTest2` table so you can use it in an `UPDATE` statement like so:

```
WITH _MinAndMax AS
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(Number) AS NumberMin,
        Max(Number) AS NumberMax
    FROM #TempTest
    WHERE Number > 1 -- Filters out anything less than or equal to 1
        AND Number < 8 -- Filters out anything greater than or equal to 8
)

UPDATE TT2
SET TT2.MaxNo = MAM.NumberMax,
    TT2.MinNo = MAM.NumberMin
FROM #TempTest2 AS TT2
CROSS JOIN _MinAndMax AS MAM;
```